# Where does the title in Universal Link smart banners come from?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

When you setup [Universal Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1) support in your iOS 9 app, by putting an apple-app-site-association file on your server and getting the app setup to handle the linking, you automatically also get smart banners on your site whenever you are viewing a page that is supported by your app.

Like this:

[image]

These are automatic banners that appear, without us putting any `meta` tags on our site. They only appear when the user is at the top of the page and pulls down (from what I can see).

My question: Where is Apple pulling the title for the banner from? In the above example, the "Yelp" that appears above the "Open in the Yelp app" line, where does that come from? What we're seeing on ours is: the app icon, the OPEN text on the right, the "Open in the XXXX app," but no title, just a blank area above that line.

I've tried adding some of the meta tags [discussed here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/WebContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH8-SW5), but it still doesn't seem to work.

I'm a bit afraid that the answer is going to be that Apple indexes some property off your webpage to get the title. The reason I'm afraid is because these particular pages are not accessible to the general public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the title is coming from the `iTunesMetadata.plist` `itemName` key.  I'm guessing this is only present in distribution ipa file.

```
<key>itemName</key>
<string>App Name</string>
```

---

### The iTunesMetadata.plist Contents

The following is an example of of typical iTunesMetadata.plist file used to define the iTunes information for an Ad Hoc distribution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <dict>
        <key>armv7</key>
        <true/>
        <key>front-facing-camera</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>

    <key>artistName</key>
    <string>Company, Inc.</string>

    <key>bundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>App Name</string>

    <key>bundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.5.1</string>

    <key>bundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.5.1</string>

    <key>copyright</key>
    <string>© 2015 Company, Inc.</string>

    <key>drmVersionNumber</key>
    <integer>0</integer>

    <key>fileExtension</key>
    <string>.app</string>

    <key>gameCenterEnabled</key>
    <false/>

    <key>gameCenterEverEnabled</key>
    <false/>

    <key>genre</key>
    <string>Games</string>

    <key>genreId</key>
    <integer>6014</integer>

    <key>itemName</key>
    <string>App Name</string>

    <key>kind</key>
    <string>software</string>

    <key>playlistArtistName</key>
    <string>Company, Inc.</string>

    <key>playlistName</key>
    <string>App Name</string>

    <key>releaseDate</key>
    <string>2015-11-18T03:23:10Z</string>

    <key>s</key>
    <integer>143441</integer>

    <key>softwareIconNeedsShine</key>
    <false/>

    <key>softwareSupportedDeviceIds</key>
    <array>
        <integer>9</integer>
    </array>

    <key>softwareVersionBundleId</key>
    <string>com.company.appid</string>

    <key>subgenres</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>genre</key>
            <string>Puzzle</string>
            <key>genreId</key>
            <integer>7012</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>genre</key>
            <string>Word</string>
            <key>genreId</key>
            <integer>7019</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>

    <key>versionRestrictions</key>
    <integer>16843008</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: How are you determining that this is true? I don't doubt that itemName is a key in the iTunesMetadata.plist file, but how have you determined that this is where the app title is pulled for the purpose of the Smart Banner?

Comment: Just extract the ipa file, and change the value of itemName.

Comment: Sorry, I was asking more along the lines of "how do you know this is what's causing the problem I'm seeing?" I.e. did you have a source for this info, or is this just a guess based on your experience? I do see a similar response about this in the apple developer forums, where someone says "It looks like the title is coming from the iTunesMetadata.plist itemName key." But they also don't say how they arrived at that conclusion. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: No, I don't have any source. I just figured out this by extracting the ipa file and chage the value of `itemName` and make package again. After packing ipa again, I installed the ipa file via Device Manager of XCode in a development mode device. And again open website in safari  and this time I seen changed value of `itemName` in banner title field. That's how I figured out.

Comment: @mason-g-zhwiti Please comment the link of apple developer forums where this discussion on going